# How do I configure RabbitMQ in windows?

Tags: rabbitmq

This is a somewhat broad question, but I can't figure out how RabbitMQ is configured. I've looked at the website and it says to create a "rabbitmq.conf" file and then create a system environment variable called "RABBITMQ_CONFIG_FILE" and set it to the location of the conf file, minus the extension. I've tried this and it doesn't work.

Specifically, I'm trying to get RabbitMQ to log in debug mode. I've also set another system environment variable, "RABBITMQ_LOG_BASE", and set it to a folder location. Instead, it's still logging to the user directory of the person who originally installed it. Where is that even stored? Is there some other config file somewhere?

What am I doing wrong here?

I'm on windows server 2016. Erlang version is 20.0 and RabbitMQ is 3.7.3.

Answer (score 0):

The following table outlines the default location of files and folders for rabbitmq on windows

[image]

So to simplify things you can remove the environment variables approach and just refer to the default locations. Please do take care to restart the rabbitmq once you clean up the variables .

Comment: The issue I'm having is that RabbitMQ is running as "Local System", but it's still logging to the user directory of the user who installed it. Why is it using that %APPDATA% instead of the %APPDATA% of the system account?